# Capture original argument from function using andThen

Tags: scala, functional-programming, function-composition

I have a function:

```
f: T => Option[T]
```

I want to use this function to compose another function in which I would capture the original argument of type T from f, when the result returned from it is None

```
g: T => T
```

The best way that I have found to to implement this is:

```
    val g: (original: T) => f andThen (_.getOrElse(original)) apply original
```

I'm still new to scala and functional programming in general. Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe using parcial applied functions?
Thank you.

Comment: `val g: T => T = { o => f(o).getOrElse(o) }` ?

Comment: Thanks @Dima sometimes one forgets to be pragmatic.